# Can you install elementary os on an ssd hard drive?

Tags: system-installation, disk-management

Can you install elementary OS on an SSD hard drive?

Comment: Of course. Have you not had success installing on an SSD?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can.

I actually cloned my full HD to a new SSD yesterday, 
and it rebooted just fine and speedying everything...

Answer (score 0):

I use a small mSATA SSD 32Gb just for the / and hdd for the /home. System start 20 seconds, poweroff 5 seconds.